# How to know where the specific third-party library pollute my app?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Today I receive the App Store's rejection of my app, look below:

> Business - 3.2.2
>
> Your app includes content or features that can manipulate the user reviews or chart ranking on the App Store. Specifically, the offer wall in your app incentivizes users to download other apps in order to receive points and currency.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please remove the following third-party library from your app:
>
> "万普"

[image]

But wonder me is I did not import any related to "万普" library.

My pods:

[image]

My manual imports library:

[image]

And I also searched my project about "万普" or "wap":

[image]

---

**Update -1**

My manual libraries fold open:

[image]

The only uncertain library is `libGeTuiSdk-1.5.3.a` and `libGtExtensionSdk-1.0.0.a`, but I have asked the `GeTui`'s service, they said "万普" is not related to them's libraries.

[image]

---

**Edit -1**

This is the three times rejected, I stated my application did not contains any thing about "万普".

[image]

Comment: Did you use any Ad Kit? If not, check all libs and frameworks.

Comment: @Lumialxk I have checked, found nothing about "万普" or "wap"(its official site is www.waps.cn)

Comment: I guess you met malicious library or framework. Pay attention to those you downloaded manually.

Comment: What is MOBFoundation_IDFA & UMengAnalytics are used for? Are you sure it's not them?

Comment: @sweta.me, ` MOBFoundation_IDFA & UMengAnalytic` are analytic the user and  statistics their use condition, other app with the `MOBFoundation_IDFA & UMengAnalytic` will pass the verify, I don't think the cause is this.

Comment: Okay. I haven't ever heard about it. So, was curious. Got some other IDFA related rejection issue thread. You might want to go through it. https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/issues/218

Comment: have you checked all of your pods dependencies' too ??

Comment: @aircraft Why doesn't you take help from the apple developers account and ask for the suggestion. When you are not using that file how you can remove it from your project or there may be any mis-concept. It saves your time too buddy & you get best suggestion too. If you raise question we can't help you because we can not check your whole project deeply. Hope you got me.

Comment: @aircraft for more info if you installing cocoapod then it is a framework in your projct , so when you search any file in your project it does not check framework, so you need to check manually.

Comment: Have you tried to re-submit the apple and mentioned that you are not using above mentioned third-party library and you can also ask them "how I can find this library in project because I am sure it's not there", some times re-submission app with comment and question will lead to app approval

Comment: @VarunNaharia, I re-submissioned 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

I have downloaded the SDK of 万普 (Waps.cn) by creating an developer account on their website. Do you recognise any of the following filenames?

```
JOYConnect.h
apilib.a
WapsAdManager.h
WapsAdManager.mm
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Before, I searched the `waps` in my project, find nothing, and now I searched your provide information, find nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

doesnt have enough reputation to put a comment.

some tips:

have you checked "`Build Phases - Compile Sources`",

also "`Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries`"?

then run **Charles**, Listen to your network.

Comment: @D Jiang, can you express more detail? the steps is what?

Comment: @aircraft i mean user Charles or Fiddler to listen your networking.